# Setup a Monit-Monitorung for GlusterFS

Tags: ubuntu, monit, glusterfs

i try to look into to monitor a GlusterFS on Ubuntu using monit. It seems that is not an easy task. Any suggestion, what is the best strategy ?

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Monit doesn't have any specific feature related to GlusterFS. Monit can monitor file, filesystem, process, etc...

It is up to you to define Monit rules according to your need.